# When is 'de' needed after a number?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, nombres

I saw this on social media:

> Si tu pouvais avoir un million de dollars américains, mais que tu ne pourrais acheter que des choses commençant par la première lettre de ton prénom...qu'achèterais-tu ?

Why is *de* needed after *million* ? I was under the impression you did not need *de* after a number. I would say "J'ai deux chats," not "J'ai deux de chats."

Comment: *Cent* dollars mais *une centaine de* dollars. [Det] [n] mais [det] [n] de [n]. Comme jlliagre le dit il est question de cardinal vs. substantif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Si tu pouvais avoir **un million dollars americains**, mais ...

... is not correct.

In the case of *ballpark* figures such as "million", "dizaine", "trentaine" etc (as opposed to exact numbers such as "deux", "dix", "soixante" etc), you need to place "de" in between:

> un million **de** chats
>
> une dizaine **de** chats
>
> une trentaine **de** chats {vs: trente chats}
>
> des centaines **de** milliers **de** chats

Comment: What if it's literally exactly *one million* ?

Comment: @Aerovistae: *de* is required in any case after *million*, *milliard*, *billion*, etc. be it a ballpark or an exact figure. There's no way to tell the difference.

Comment: @Aerovistae Hi. I just used the term "ballpark/approximate figure" in comparison to exact numbers such as "dix". It doesn't matter whether the number you have in mind is exactly a million or a little over it; "de" cannot be dropped. Perhaps, there is a grammatical term for describing these  numbers.

Comment: *Million*, *milliard* are substantives while *deux*, *dix*, *trente* are cardinal adjectives.

Comment: Is this also true for *deux million*, *trois million*, etc? I would assume so. But not for *deux million un*.

Comment: @Aerovistae Yes, "deux million**s** **de** dollars".

Comment: "Deux millions de dollars, deux millions un dollar".....strange. Ok. Merci.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with *million/milliard*. On the one hand, they are measure nouns belonging to the same series as *dizaine/centaine/millier* but contrary to the latter, they act like *mètre/litre*:

- *un mètre de tissu, un mètre cinquante de tissu*
- *un litre de lait, un litre vingt-cinq de lait*
- *un million d'euros, un million deux d'euros*
- *un millier d'euros, ?un millier deux d'euros?*

On the other hand, they are cardinal building units (like *dix/cent/mille*) with the special property of demanding *de* marked nouns when they stand on the right margin:

- 999 999 pages, un million de pages, un million une pages
- deux milliards cent millions de pages, deux milliards cent millions une page

In the last examples above, they are not measure nouns because the first one is not understood as 2 000 000 100 x millions, and the second one runs into the same problem with the added quirk that the decimal parts have to be masculine.